# Laravel 5.2 database scheme creates an unique column by it self

Tags: php, laravel, database-schema, laravel-5

I've the following schema for creating the addresses table:

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('id')->index();
    $table->string('street', 100);
    $table->integer('number', 5);
    $table->string('addition', 10);
    $table->string('postal_code', 7);
    $table->string('place', 45);
    $table->string('country', 45);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

For security reasons, 'id' is an random generated and unique string instead of an auto increment integer.

Just one problem: Laravel makes the column 'number' unique, because it is the only column with data type integer. We want the column 'id' as primary and unique key.

We also tried this:

```
$table->primary('id')->index();
$table->uuid('id')->index();
$table->string('id')->primary()->index();
```

I'm still getting this error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed:
>   addresses.number

Comment: I'm going to comment about something else here - you're using a random generated unique string instead of auto_increment because of security reasons - what reasons are those? If you don't want to expose the numeric ID, why don't you deliver an encoded one or encrypt it, base64_encode it and deliver that? You are going to have a very, very bad time otherwise and you'll learn why when your data grows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->uuid('id')->primary();
      $table->integer('number', false);
  });
```

Comment: This worked nearly, I still had an error because Laravel created two primary keys: id and number. So I changed $table->integer('number', 5) to $table->integer('number', false); The second parameter disabled 'auto increment'.

Comment: Interesting... I edited my answer to match your.. Though I have to say that I checked and Laravel did not make the number column primary key for me for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. Check out this article: http://garrettstjohn.com/article/using-uuids-laravel-eloquent-orm/

Pretty much what is happening is that Laravel "says" they support UUID's but they really need a helping hand.

Your schema will work, but just to be sure, I use it as this:

```
$table->primary('id');
```

After using the article's provided examples, you should have something similar to this (this is my User model):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    // UuidForKey is a custom trait added in the app folder
    use SoftDeletes, UuidForKey;

    // This disabled the auto-incrementing
    public $incrementing = false;

    // Make sure id is set as primary
    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    // Makes sure that the id is a string and not an integer
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'string',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'email',
        'password',
        'role',
        'active',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```